# Unable to Connect to Localhost in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

I've just started using MySQL workbench and I tried to make a connection however when I do it I get this error. I've installed MySql as well and I've tried to look at the mysql workbench document to figure out what was going on but can't seem to figure it out. I'm wondering if someone else has had this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If windows check service has been started.

Comment: @P.Salmon how do I do that?

Comment: a-confirm you are using windows b-if you are type services into the type here to search box at the bottom left of your screen and scroll down to mysql and if manual start it if running restart it. If you don't see it at all then you did not install it.